# crop image in android lollipop device

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

How do we pick and crop an image from gallery and camera on a lollipop device? If any one has a code or example then please share with me. I am stuck with this. I didn't find any solution from past 7 days on the Internet.

Comment: Check this library. It supports many features for editing pictures. https://github.com/imgly/imgly-sdk-android-demo

Comment: thanks for the suggestion,i will definately try it.